# sql BIT to Java

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, types, type-conversion

My sqlserver table has a column designed as a BIT datatype.  It has values 1 and 0s

Then in my Java code, I do

```
result = new ArrayList
result.add( (Boolean)(rs.getBoolean("columnName")));
```

Then when I read the value from the list - it shows as `Long`.
According to everything I find, it says hat a `BIT` datatype is supposed to map to `boolean`.

Why does it come as `Long`?
What can be done to fix this?

Comment: Based on your comments to @mureinik, it seems you haven't actually posted the code that is causing the problem. Please edit your question to include the part of your program where you're finding that this boolean value has changed to a long.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call `getBoolean` directly and let it take care of all the casting/coverting:

```
result.add(rs.getBoolean("columnName"));
```

Comment: Hey .. sorry.  I made a typo.  I am calling it as you say.  I call getBoolean.. not just "get".  And it comes as Long in a list

Comment: `getBoolean` returns a `boolean`. There's no way it can return a `Long`. Perhaps you are calling `getObject`?

Comment: It returns boolean and I can see the value true/false in eclipse debugger - inspecting an element.  However, when I get to retrieve that value from the list (I add it to result list), it comes as Long with values 1 or 0 (in place of true/false) .  That is the problem.  !!

Comment: Can you show how you're using the list? Java doesn't promote booleans to longs out of the box.

Comment: Thanks.  I figured out that a problem was in a different place.  Apparently my deployment got corrupted and I was "redeploying" the older version - thinking it was a fixed one .  :)